# Google Calendar error when trying to share

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-calendar-api

I have this service account "testname@myapp-123456.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
My clients are using this account to share their Google Calendar.
Scenario 1.
Last couple of days ,when a users tries to insert this account to their google calendar sharing
(Share with specific people--> Add people) they get
an error "Something went wrong.Please try again later"
Scenario 2
Many clients have already add this share (when it was working correctly)
When a user tries to remove this share he get also this error.
Practically he is not able to remove his Google calendar share with us.
IS there something wrong with Google or do i miss something ?
Thank you for any help

Comment: After much reading it seems to be obvious that a service account email cannot be added to the "share with people" setting on the calendars settings.Is there another way to keep this functionality ?
At the moment i have over 200 clients that have shared their calendar with the service account.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be intentional. See: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/148804709

> Status: Won't Fix (Intended Behavior)
> Hello,
>
> Thank you for creating this issue.
>
> That's right. Due to a recent change of behaviour, any account has to explicitly "accept" a Calendar that has been shared with them. In case of a Service Account, this "acceptance" should be made by adding the calendar to the CalendarList via CalendarList.insert [1].

Comment: Thats what i am doing now.I am adding shared calendars to my CalendarList via CalendarList.Insert.The issue is that no one can share his Calendar by adding my Service Account to the 'Share with specific people'.As soon as they push the send button a 'Something went wrong..." message appears.